# Filter changing file periodically and redirect filtered output to new file

Tags: grep, read, filter

Suppose I have `log.txt`

The sample of log.txt are like these format:
`Code Data Timestamp`

```
...
C:57 hello 1644498429
C:56 world 1644498430
C:57 water 1644498433
...
```

If I want filter string line that contain `C:57` I can achieve it with

`cat log.txt | grep C:57`

then I redirect output to the new file hence

`cat log.txt | grep C:57 > filtered_log.txt`

How ever when there's new change in log.txt, I should repeat execute that command again. I want it executes periodically or for every new change in file or  only when there's new line that contain string `C:57`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tail -f` thusly:

```
tail -f log.txt|grep C:57 >> filtered_log.txt
```

This continuously reads `log.txt` grepping for the token `C:57` and adding any matches to the `filtered.log.txt`.

The use of `cat` to read the log and pipe that to `grep` is a useless use of `cat`. `grep` can directly read a file. You're wasting I/O by combining a `cat` and a `grep`.

The one drawback here is that the appearance of filtered output may be delayed due to buffering. This can be circumvented with:

```
tail -f log.txt|grep --line-buffered C:57 >> filtered_log.txt
```

or by using the `stdbuf -o0` command:

```
 tail -f log.txt|stdbuf -o0|grep C:57 >> filtered_log.txt C:57
```

Comment: I was trying the same, be careful the filtered_log.txt is not updated right away, for me it was at 4096 bytes.

Comment: @lolesque The updates of the filtered_log.txt will indeed be delayed by buffering and the  usual buffer size is 4096 characters.

Comment: ```tail: log.txt: file truncated```

Comment: I add example line manually with string that contain ```C:57``` in log.txt by ```nano``` and it didn't update to filtered_log.txt with get that received error.

Comment: To add new lines to be seen by a running `tail -f`, echo them with appending redirection to the logfile from a second session.